# How can I use tesseract ocr onto Unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, tesseract

I did a search on the web, and I got confused. So i'm taking my question here. Any answers here will very much be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Extremly vague and unspecific [“_How can i use / How do i start_”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226103/are-point-me-in-the-right-direction-questions-acceptable) questions are not a good fit for StackOverflow, as they cannot be answered without requiring or provking long-winded, opinionated and possibly open-ended discussions. Please take the [tour], and familiarize yourself with [ask] (preferably with a [mcve]) here on StackOverflow.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about a GUI interface on Ubuntu/Linux. Maybe Software Recommendations SE would be a better place to ask this.